# Reuse Scalafmt Config File Across Projects

Tags: scala, scalafmt

I have a set of Scala projects and for all of those projects, I would like to introduce some scala source code formatting for which purpose, I'm using the scamafmt sbt pliugin. I have compiled the config file and this config file is in a separate project repo. I would now like to reuse this in all of the other Scala projects. I see two possibilities:

1. Use the repo where the conf file is located as a git submodule in all the other 10 projects where I want to run the scala  formatter
2. Do not do anything, just add a README documentation that every user who is working on the codebase should download the scalafmt conf file to the project (I will pre add a .gitignore to all projects to ignore the local conf file)

Is there any other approach? I definitely do not want the conf file to diverge if I leave it as is in all the projects.

Comment: Note that you probably don't want option 2 anyway because it means you can't assert on the formatting in your CI.

Comment: So you mean option 1 is a good idea?

Comment: With Option 1, what if out of the 10 projects, 5 of them change the formatting? The rest of the 5 should pull the latest changes. Correct? Is using git submodules a good practice?

Comment: I'm always against git submodules. Don't think it's a good option either 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation, one option is to build (and publish in your org) a SBT plugin with your configuration:

https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#share-configuration-between-builds

> To share configuration across different sbt builds, create a custom sbt plugin that generates .scalafmt-common.conf on build reload, then include the generated file from .scalafmt.conf
>
> ```
> // project/MyScalafmtPlugin.scala
> import sbt._
> object MyScalafmtPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
>   override def trigger = allRequirements
>   override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
>   override def buildSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
>     SettingKey[Unit]("scalafmtGenerateConfig") :=
>       IO.write(
>         // writes to file once when build is loaded
>         file(".scalafmt-common.conf"),
>         "maxColumn = 100".stripMargin.getBytes("UTF-8")
>       )
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> // .scalafmt.conf
> include ".scalafmt-common.conf"
> ```

Comment: I'm now stuck with calling this plugin. I have it published locally, but now sure how to get it triggered. I have raised a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965732/sbt-plugin-published-locally-fails-with-an-error-when-included-in-a-project